# Google Closure Compiler coerce type from EventTarget to Node

Tags: javascript, google-closure

I'm trying to compile my program which has a click event listener on an image and I am trying to check to see if that click happened on a particular element or on some other element.

```
function(e){
    var img_wrapper = goog.dom.getElementsByClass('imgWrapper');
    if (img_wrapper.length > 0 &&  goog.dom.findCommonAncestor(e.target, img_wrapper[0]) === img_wrapper[0]){
        return;
    }
}
```

When I compile, I get this error:

```
flickr_closure.js:226: WARNING - actual parameter 1 of goog.dom.findCommonAncestor does not match formal parameter
found   : (EventTarget|null)
required: (Node|null|undefined)
  if (img_wrapper.length > 0 &&  goog.dom.findCommonAncestor(e.target, img_wrapper[0]) === img_wrapper[0]){
                                                         ^

0 error(s), 1 warning(s), 97.0% typed
```

The code works like I want it to, but I still get that warning, and since this is for a school assignment, one of the requirements is that I can't have warnings when compiled.

I've tried adding some basic type information for `e.target` to try to tell the compiler to treat it as a Node, but it complains about that too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use so-called [type-casting](https://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/wiki/AnnotatingTypes):

```
/** @type {Node} */ (e.target)
```

e.g.

```
goog.dom.findCommonAncestor(/** @type {Node} */ (e.target), img_wrapper[0])
```

Comment: I had tried this but it didn't work because I neglected to include the parenthesis around `e.target`. Thanks for the reminder that I needed the parens.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on [Alex's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23101391/108009), it is good practise to type-cast after actually checking the variable.

```
if(goog.dom.isElement(e.target)) {
  .... /** @type {!Element} */ (e.target) ....
}
```